# colcon_release_cross kinetic driveworks failed

Tags: ros, compile, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ENV:
Autoware 1.11.1 and 1.12.alpha1,2
ROS1.
Cross compile generic-aarch64 is OK, but cross compile driveworks always got error,

log:

> --- stderr: ndt_gpu
> CMake Warning at
> /sysroot/driveworks/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by
> "autoware_build_flags" with any of the
> following names:
>
> ```
> autoware_build_flagsConfig.cmake
> autoware_build_flags-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of
> "autoware_build_flags" to
> CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH   or set
> "autoware_build_flags_DIR" to a
> directory containing one of the
> above files.  If
> "autoware_build_flags" provides a
> separate development   package or SDK,
> be sure it has been installed. Call
> Stack (most recent call first):
>
> CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
>
> CMake Error at
> /sysroot/driveworks/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83
> (find_package):   Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by
> "autoware_build_flags" with any of the
> following names:
>
> ```
> autoware_build_flagsConfig.cmake
> autoware_build_flags-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of
> "autoware_build_flags" to
> CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH   or set
> "autoware_build_flags_DIR" to a
> directory containing one of the
> above files.  If
> "autoware_build_flags" provides a
> separate development   package or SDK,
> be sure it has been installed. Call
> Stack (most recent call first):
> CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
>
> --- Failed   <<< ndt_gpu  [ Exited with code 1 ]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327667/colcon_release_cross-kinetic-driveworks-failed/) by [sdyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/43908/sdyy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-07-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/43908/sdyy/) on 2019-07-04**:
I may know why is failed, because after colcon build, some packages were not installed.
But I don't know why there were not installed

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-07-05**:
@sdyy - Can you please try the version on the `master` branch of `autoware`? Please post the output of the following commands inside your `autoware` folder:

```
git remote get-url origin
cd ros && ls && cd ..
```

Please be aware: The `colcon_release_cross` still expects all of the dependent repositories to be in the `ros/` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this issue is caused by
cross_toolchain_driveworks.cmake

> set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
> "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/opt/ros/kinetic")

mark this line will be OK.

By the way, if want to build all packages, will be still fail. In driveworks docker image, it leaks some packages, need to install.

---

Originally posted by [sdyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/43908/sdyy/) with karma: 26 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1